# Wicket: Update Model on DropDownChoice Item Selection Event

Tags: java, scala, wicket

I need to update a model or object immediately after select
a DropDownChoice item.

Bellow is the code that I'm working:

```
add(new ListView[Company]("listCompanies", listData) {

    override protected def onBeforeRender() {
      //
      // ...
      super.onBeforeRender()
    }

    def populateItem(item: ListItem[Company]) = {
      var company = item.getModelObject()

      //...

      val listClients: java.util.List[Client] = clientControler.listClients


      item.add(new DropDownChoice("clientSelection", listClients,new ChoiceRenderer[Client]("name")))
```

In the Listview with properties of Company Object,
after choose a name property of the DropDownChoice, the model
Company would be updated with the Client Name selected.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I think you can override onSelectionChanged. But you also need to override wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications to return true to make it work. Something like this.

```
    DropDownChoice<Client> dropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice("clientSelection", listClients) {
        @Override
        protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSelectionChanged(Object newSelection) {
            // Do something here when selection is changed
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to add updating behavior:

```
    add(new DropDownChoice<Client>("clientSelection", listClients)
                .add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

// update your model here
// then you need to add model to target
                        target.add();
                    }
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an AjaxEventBehavior on your DropDownChoice:

```
item.add(new DropDownChoice("clientSelection", listClients,new ChoiceRenderer[Client("name")).add(new AjaxEventBehavior("change") {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }))
```